# Which sentence sounds most natural to you? Why?

Tags: grammar, british-english

Which sentence sounds most natural to you? Why?

- We have on this earth what makes life worth living.
- On this earth what makes life worth living.
- On this earth there is that which deserves life.

Answer (score 2):

#1 is the more natural.

You could also say, "On this earth we have what makes life worth living."

#2 is not a complete sentence. There's a prepositional phrase ... and that's all. No subject, no predicate.

#3 is grammatically correct but awkward. We generally avoid phrases like "there is that which" and try to just name the thing you're talking about directly. And by the way, #3 doesn't mean the same as #1 or #2. You switched from "makes life worth living" to "which deserves life". "Makes life worth living" means things that are pleasant or satisfying. Like people will say that having someone you love or a job that is satisfying makes life worth living, or if they're being more whimsical they might say chocolate bars or some form of entertainment. But "deserves life" means "is worthy of having been born", as opposed to someone or some animal that is worthless and no one would object to them being killed.

Comment: I would say that #2 is a complete sentence, but poorly punctuated, and it poses a question: "On this earth, what makes life worth living?"

Comment: @rjpond Okay, yes, turn it into a question and it's valid. I'll give you that.